# A template that extends another one cannot start with a byte order mark (BOM); it must be removed in "index.twig" at line 1

Tags: symfony, encoding, utf-8, twig, bolt-cms

Hi i was using bolt and twig and i got this error

> A template that extends another one cannot start with a byte order mark (BOM); it must be removed in "index.twig" at line 1.

but I cant seem to find out what the problem here is. searched arround on the internet found some answers here on stack  [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29139471/symfony2-error-twig-a-template-that-extends-another-one-cannot-have-a-body)  this one. but this didnt seem to help for me.

my _master.twig file looks like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   {% block SEO %}
   {% endblock %}
   {% include "partials/_head.twig" %}
</head>
<body>
   {% include "partials/_header.twig" %}
   {% block content %}
   {% enblock %}
   {% include "partials/_footer.twig" %}
   {% include "partials/_scripts.twig" %}
</body>
</html>
```

And my index.twig like this

```
{% extends "partials/_master.twig" %}

{% block SEO %}
  <title>Home</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Beschrijving"/>
  <meta name="keywords" content="woordjes, enzo"/>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="page"...>
{% endblock %}
```

ive had some other bolt/twig projects but this is how i did it everytime now suddenly it gives me back this error. i hope someone can help me solve this error.

Comment: You must encode your file with UTF8 without BOM : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom

Comment: ok i can understand that. but how do i get rid of the BOM?

Comment: Oh ehm. im using phpstorm and i just switched from utf-8 to a windows encoding. and switched back to utf-8 and then it worked

Comment: @MathieuDormeval your answer i read the linked page and someone there said to reswitch from utf to something else. and back. so can u put your comment in a answer so i can click the hook?

Comment: You can choose to encode your document without BOM in your favorite IDE

Comment: Ah ok. i set encoding type to pure utf-8 now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an encoding problem.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom), you must encode your document with UTF-8 without BOM.

Best regards,

Comment: yes that was exactly what was the problem. sorry for my late reaction. one of my colleague's pointed it out to me. but its stil the good answer so thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

So this happened to me again. For people reading this post in the future,

If you open files that are a bit old or outdated then PHP storm may change the encoding type for some reason.

So if you open older files. keep in mind that PHP storm may change the encoding.

Hope this helps, happy coding!